# Intuitive explanation of COSMIC TIME?

Tags: cosmology, coordinate-systems, time, space-expansion, cosmological-inflation

I came across the following statement, while studying a Newtonian model for cosmic expansion:

> "If $R(t)$ is the scaling factor, we can define the Hubble parameter as $H(t)=\frac{\dot{R(t)}}{R(t)}$, being $t$ the cosmic time."

What is the definition of cosmic time? Is it the same for all observers?

Comment: Came across where? Which page?

Comment: *What is the definition of cosmic time?* Wikipedia: [Cosmic time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_time)

Comment: @Qmechanic notes from my professor

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cosmic time is defined as the (proper) time experienced by an observer at rest in a co-mobile frame, that is a frame carried by the expansion in an isotropic and homogeneous Universe (As such, it is an idealization). If you wish, it is the time measured by a clock for an observer which is motionless with respect to the average of the homogeneous matter distribution in the Universe, and hence carried along with it by the expansion. If the Universe really is isotropic and homogeneous, all co-mobile observers should measure the same cosmic-time between two events.

Assuming isotropy and homogeneity is an hypothesis at the basis of all modern cosmology, called the "cosmological principle". It seems to be well verified on the largest scales of the Universe, as well as in the CMB, which is the oldest source of observable light in the Universe (It is however of course possible to question this principle, as e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.8473). Assuming the cosmological principle and all its symmetry simplifies drastically the description of the Universe and its evolution within GR, and allows to define unambiguously the cosmic time as above.